# Simple routes in rail3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, subdomain

I'm trying to an admin subdomain to provide some back-end protected access to my site.

I'm seeing lots of rather complex tutorials on how to make subdomains to match any string, but I just want something simple.

In my route, I have

```
 constraints(:subdomain => 'admin') do
    resources :admin
    root :to => 'admin#index'
  end
```

but this doesn't resolve.

I'm running my development in an ubuntu virtual machine, so I connect through the ip address, not localhost, so most of the questions where people have problems because of localhost I don't think apply to me.

Anybody know what I've got wrong?

Comment: you need to handle this through ```/etc/hosts``` and provide a real hostname when connecting like admin.example.com

Comment: thanks @phoet, you were correct. If you provide this as the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to handle this through /etc/hosts and provide a real hostname when connecting like admin.example.com

Comment: I'm using fiddler, so what I did was update my hosts file, and set fiddler to point to the port number.